# as3 How to use swap with array list?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, connect

I have Array list, and in this array have 4 url and port, i want when user connect from index[0] then connection lose i show button when click user this button i want to connect same port but second url like index[1].

How i solve and how can i do please help thanks. This is my List

```
private static var urisToTry:Array = [
            new SocketUri("123.net", 123),
            new SocketUri("1234.net", 123),
            new SocketUri("123.net", 321),
            new SocketUri("1234.net", 321)
        ];
```

Any help would be great i need pseudo code

Comment: 1) Keep index of currently selected one and every time you lost connection, increase it. Check if index is less than array length.

2) Keep using index 0, but every time you lost connection, move 1st element from the list to the end. `urisToTry.push(urisToTry.shift())`

Comment: thanks for answering do you have any pseudo code ? @3vilguy

Comment: Um, yeah:
`when connection lost:`
`getNextUrl;`
`connect using new url;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
// current array index
private var connIndex:int = 0;

public function connect():void
{
    var mySocketURI:SocketUri = urisToTry[connIndex];

    // do your connection here
}

private function onConnectionLost():void
{
    // increase index and check if it is within array length
    if(connIndex >= urisToTry.length -1)
        connIndex = 0;
    else
        connIndex++;

    connect();
}
```